# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #9](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9) on Mathematics has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: TheSimpliFire]

[image: Paramanand Singh]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please also join me in thanking [Michael Greinecker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21674/michael-greinecker) who will be stepping down from the team.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4713780039647232).